# What is the formula to find the yield rate?

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

One bond, with a face value of 1000 dollars and annual coupons at a rate of 7.6 percent effective, has a price of 1146.17 dollars. A second bond, with a face value of 1000 dollars and annual coupons at a rate of 6.1 percent effective, has a price of 1050.43 dollars. Both bonds are redeemable at par in the same number of years, and have the same yield rate. Find the yield rate. ?

What is the formula to find the yield rate? I can't find any that include the variables that I was given in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The prices of the two bonds are
$$
\begin{align}
1146.17&=76\,a_{\overline{n}|r}+1000\,v^n \tag 1\\
1050.43&=61\,a_{\overline{n}|r}+1000\,v^n \tag 2\\
\end{align}
$$
and solving the system we find
$$
\begin{align}
a_{\overline{n}|r}&=6.38267=\frac{1-v^n}{r}\tag 3\\
v^n&=0.661087=\frac{1}{(1+r)^n}\tag 4
\end{align}
$$
From $(3)$ and $(4)$ we find 
$$
r=\frac{1-0.661087}{6.38267}\approx 5.31\%\tag 5
$$
and from $(4)$ and $(5)$ we have
$$
n=-\frac{\log 0.661087}{\log(1+0.0531)}\approx 8\tag 6
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for that in depth answer! Would have never seen this perspective on my own. Feel like I've such a better understand of yield rate now ! @alexjo